How to only get some flutter quill toolbar buttons?
I am creating an app using Dart in AndroidStudio and want to use flutter_quill 10.1.6 to create the toolbar for a text page (similar to docs/word/notion)
I have been trying for days using 10.1.4 and got till here with the toolbar created using ChatGPT. Here is the code for that:
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart' as quill;

  void main() {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }

  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Quill Editor Example'),
          ),
          body: QuillEditorExample(),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  class QuillEditorExample extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _QuillEditorExampleState createState() => _QuillEditorExampleState();
  }

  class _QuillEditorExampleState extends State<QuillEditorExample> {
    final quill.QuillController _controller = quill.QuillController.basic();

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          quill.QuillToolbar.simple(
            controller: _controller,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: quill.QuillEditor(
              controller: _controller,
              scrollController: ScrollController(),
              focusNode: FocusNode(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

And this is the screenshot of that page that ChatGPT coded.

If I only want certain buttons like bold, italics, underline, numbered list, font size and font colour from this toolbar in my app, how do I change the code? What do I do?
After learning all of this I want to integrate it into the page I have coded so far (using AI). Here is the code snippet of the tab/page.
            body: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: [
                quill.QuillEditor.basic(
                  controller: _quillController,
                ),

I am also attaching the entire code of the page below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';  // Import dart:typed_data
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:video_thumbnail/video_thumbnail.dart';  // Import
import 'OpeningPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart' as quill;


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Insite',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: OpeningPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  final TextEditingController _notesController = TextEditingController();
  final quill.QuillController _quillController = quill.QuillController.basic();
  String _label = 'Untitled'; //Edit

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    _loadLabel();
  }

  Future<void> _loadLabel() async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _firestore.collection('settings').doc('headerLabel').get();
    if (snapshot.exists) {
      setState(() {
        _label = snapshot['label'];
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _saveLabel(String label) async {
    await _firestore.collection('settings').doc('headerLabel').set({
      'label': label,
    });
    setState(() {
      _label = label;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _notesController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _saveNoteToFirebase(String note) async {
    await _firestore.collection('notes').add({
      'note': note,
      'date': DateTime.now().toString(),
      'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  }

  Future<void> _uploadImage(File imageFile) async {
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images/$fileName').putFile(imageFile);
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
    String imageUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    await _firestore.collection('images').add({
      'imageUrl': imageUrl,
      'label': 'Untitled',
      'date': DateTime.now().toString(),
      'time': DateTime.now().toString(),
      'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  }

  Future<void> _uploadVideo(File videoFile) async {
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('videos/$fileName').putFile(videoFile);
    TaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask;
    String videoUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    await _firestore.collection('videos').add({
      'videoUrl': videoUrl,
      'label': 'Untitled',
      'date': DateTime.now().toString(),
      'time': DateTime.now().toString(),
      'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
  }

  Future<void> getImage(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      File imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      _uploadImage(imageFile);
    }
  }

  Future<void> getVideo(ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickVideo(source: source);
    if (pickedFile != null) {
      File videoFile = File(pickedFile.path);
      _uploadVideo(videoFile);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _deleteImage(String docId, String imageUrl) async {
    try {
      // Delete the image from Firebase Storage
      await FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(imageUrl).delete();
      // Delete the document from Firestore
      await _firestore.collection('images').doc(docId).delete();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error deleting image: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _deleteVideo(String docId, String videoUrl) async {
    try {
      // Delete the video from Firebase Storage
      await FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(videoUrl).delete();
      // Delete the document from Firestore
      await _firestore.collection('videos').doc(docId).delete();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error deleting video: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 200.0,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, bottom: 16),
                title: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async {
                    String? newLabel = await showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        String labelText = _label;
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Edit Label'),
                          content: TextField(
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              labelText = value;
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter new label"),
                          ),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            TextButton(
                              child: Text('OK'),
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop(labelText);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                    if (newLabel != null && newLabel.isNotEmpty) {
                      _saveLabel(newLabel);
                        // Update the label of the placeholder image
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    _label,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                      shadows: [
                        Shadow(
                          offset: Offset(0, 1),
                          blurRadius: 3,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                background: FutureBuilder(
                  future: _firestore.collection('images').orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).limit(1).get(),
                  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(child: Text('Something went wrong'));
                    }

                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                    }

                    String headerImageUrl = snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty ? snapshot.data!.docs.first['imageUrl'] : '';
                    return Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                      children: [
                        Image.network(
                          headerImageUrl.isNotEmpty ? headerImageUrl : 'https://via.placeholder.com/800x400',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                            Colors.transparent,
                            Colors.transparent,
                            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                          ],
                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Shared With:',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 8),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.blue, child: Text('A')),
                        SizedBox(width: 8),
                        CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.red, child: Text('B')),
                        SizedBox(width: 8),
                        CircleAvatar(backgroundColor: Colors.green, child: Text('C')),
                        // Add more circles as needed
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  labelColor: Colors.black,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                  indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                  indicatorWeight: 2.0,
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                  tabs: [
                    Tab(text: 'Notes'),
                    Tab(text: 'Photos'),
                    Tab(text: 'Videos'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              pinned: true,
            ),
          ];
        },
                body: TabBarView(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: [
                    quill.QuillEditor.basic(
                      controller: _quillController,
                    ),

            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore.collection('images').orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                }

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }

                List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> imagesDocs = snapshot.data!.docs;
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      childAspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                    ),
                    itemCount: imagesDocs.length + 1,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      if (index == 0) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            showModalBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return SafeArea(
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      ListTile(
                                        leading: Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                                        title: Text('Take a Photo'),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                          getImage(ImageSource.camera);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      ListTile(
                                        leading: Icon(Icons.photo_library),
                                        title: Text('Choose from Library'),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                          getImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.grey[300],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 50),
                          ),
                        );
                      }

                      Map<String, dynamic> data = imagesDocs[index - 1].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      String imageUrl = data['imageUrl'];
                      String date = data['date'];
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ImageViewPage(
                                imageUrl: imageUrl,
                                date: date,
                                time: date,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                child: Container(
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    date,
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              top: -10,
                              right: -10,
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // Call your delete function here
                                  _deleteImage(imagesDocs[index - 1].id, imageUrl);
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore.collection('videos').orderBy('timestamp', descending: true).snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                }

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }

                List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> videosDocs = snapshot.data!.docs;
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      childAspectRatio: 1 / 1,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                    ),
                    itemCount: videosDocs.length + 1,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      if (index == 0) {
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            showModalBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return SafeArea(
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      ListTile(
                                        leading: Icon(Icons.videocam),
                                        title: Text('Record Video'),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                          getVideo(ImageSource.camera);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      ListTile(
                                        leading: Icon(Icons.video_library),
                                        title: Text('Choose from Library'),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Navigator.pop(context);
                                          getVideo(ImageSource.gallery);
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.grey[300],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(Icons.add, size: 50),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                     //// Rest of the Code


Answer is based on version: "10.4.0". Yours might differ slightly.
Add configurations parameter to the following piece.
quill.QuillToolbar.simple(
  controller: _controller,
),

Your configurations can look something like this
final config = QuillSimpleToolbarConfigurations(
  multiRowsDisplay: true,
  showDividers: false,
  showFontFamily: false,
  showFontSize: true,
  showBoldButton: true,
  showItalicButton: true,
  showLineHeightButton: false,
  showStrikeThrough: false,
  showInlineCode: false,
  showColorButton: true,
  showBackgroundColorButton: true,
  showClearFormat: false,
  showAlignmentButtons: true,
  showHeaderStyle: false,
  showListNumbers: true,
  showListBullets: true,
  showListCheck: false,
  showCodeBlock: false,
  showQuote: false,
  showIndent: false,
  showLink: true,
  showUndo: true,
  showRedo: true,
  showDirection: false,
  showSearchButton: false,
  showSubscript: false,
  showSuperscript: false,
  showClipboardCut: false,
  showClipboardCopy: false,
  showClipboardPaste: false,
);

